# Как распарсить csv файл в python

Tags: python

Подскажите, с чего начать и как это сделать?
Есть csv файл полученный с помощью asterisk. Собственно вот его содержимое

```
"autodialer","2222","i","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000097;1","","Goto","zvonar-informer,background","2021-03-15 08:23:10","2021-03-15 08:23:21","2021-03-15 08:23:46",36,25,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796590.5115",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000097;2","SIP/zadarma-00001261","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:23:10","2021-03-15 08:23:21","2021-03-15 08:23:46",36,25,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796590.5116",""


"autodialer","2222","1","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000098;1","","Hangup","","2021-03-15 08:27:05","2021-03-15 08:27:17","2021-03-15 08:27:28",23,11,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796825.5122",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000098;2","SIP/zadarma-00001266","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:27:05","2021-03-15 08:27:17","2021-03-15 08:27:28",23,11,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796825.5123",""


"autodialer","2222","t","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000099;1","","Goto","zvonar-informer,background","2021-03-15 08:35:48","2021-03-15 08:35:59","2021-03-15 08:36:32",44,33,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797348.5157",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000099;2","SIP/zadarma-00001287","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:35:48","2021-03-15 08:35:59","2021-03-15 08:36:32",44,33,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797348.5158",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009a;2","SIP/zadarma-00001292","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:39:14","2021-03-15 08:39:29","2021-03-15 08:39:34",20,5,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797554.5171",""
"autodialer","2222","2222","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009a;1","","BackGround","zvonar","2021-03-15 08:39:14","2021-03-15 08:39:29","2021-03-15 08:39:34",20,5,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797554.5170",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009b;2","SIP/zadarma-00001295","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:40:19",,"2021-03-15 08:40:50",30,0,"NO ANSWER","DOCUMENTATION","1615797619.5176",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009c;2","SIP/zadarma-00001296","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:41:02",,"2021-03-15 08:41:14",11,0,"BUSY","DOCUMENTATION","1615797662.5179",""
```

Первые 2 строки - абонент 2222 вызвал номер 89039904644 через контекст zvonar-dialer, абонент ответил, с голосовым меню IVR он не взаимодействовал, прослушал сообщение повторно и звонок был завершен.

Вторые 2 строки - абонент 2222 вызвал номер 89039904644 через контекст zvonar-dialer, абонент ответил, в голосовом меню он нажал единицу и звонок завершился.
и т.д.

Собственно вопрос, как скрестить эти пары строк с помощью python и получить первую строку, которая содержит в себе **"i"** или **"1"** или **"t"** или **"89039904644"** игнорируя при этом остальные строки которые содержат в себе текст "Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009a;**2**"

Или всё таки попробовать взаимодействовать с таблицей cdr через pycursor

Comment: В файле есть пустые строки, или вы их добавили для наглядности?

Comment: Добавил для наглядности)

Answer (score 2):

`Pandas` нормально читает даже и с пустыми строками. Если прямо из строковой переменной, то вот:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = '''
"autodialer","2222","i","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000097;1","","Goto","zvonar-informer,background","2021-03-15 08:23:10","2021-03-15 08:23:21","2021-03-15 08:23:46",36,25,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796590.5115",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000097;2","SIP/zadarma-00001261","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:23:10","2021-03-15 08:23:21","2021-03-15 08:23:46",36,25,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796590.5116",""


"autodialer","2222","1","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000098;1","","Hangup","","2021-03-15 08:27:05","2021-03-15 08:27:17","2021-03-15 08:27:28",23,11,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796825.5122",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000098;2","SIP/zadarma-00001266","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:27:05","2021-03-15 08:27:17","2021-03-15 08:27:28",23,11,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615796825.5123",""


"autodialer","2222","t","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000099;1","","Goto","zvonar-informer,background","2021-03-15 08:35:48","2021-03-15 08:35:59","2021-03-15 08:36:32",44,33,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797348.5157",""
"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-00000099;2","SIP/zadarma-00001287","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:35:48","2021-03-15 08:35:59","2021-03-15 08:36:32",44,33,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797348.5158",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009a;2","SIP/zadarma-00001292","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:39:14","2021-03-15 08:39:29","2021-03-15 08:39:34",20,5,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797554.5171",""
"autodialer","2222","2222","zvonar-informer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009a;1","","BackGround","zvonar","2021-03-15 08:39:14","2021-03-15 08:39:29","2021-03-15 08:39:34",20,5,"ANSWERED","DOCUMENTATION","1615797554.5170",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009b;2","SIP/zadarma-00001295","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:40:19",,"2021-03-15 08:40:50",30,0,"NO ANSWER","DOCUMENTATION","1615797619.5176",""


"autodialer","2222","89039904644","zvonar-dialer",""""" <2222>","Local/89039904644@zvonar-dialer-0000009c;2","SIP/zadarma-00001296","Dial","SIP/zadarma/+79039904644,40","2021-03-15 08:41:02",,"2021-03-15 08:41:14",11,0,"BUSY","DOCUMENTATION","1615797662.5179",""
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))
```

А так в `pd.read_csv` обычно имя `csv`-файла передают.

Ну и дальше уже в `df` удобное табличное представление ваших данных.